# How to make validate in name, I want to make only alphabet is fill in this field

Tags: yii2

Code to validate the input:

```
public function rules() { 
    return [ [['name', 'email', 'subject', 'content'], 'required'], 
             [['date_added'], 'safe'],
             [['email', 'subject'], 'string', 'max' => 255], [['email'], 'email'], 
]; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a match pattern

```
    public function rules() { 
    return [ [['name', 'email', 'subject', 'content'], 'required'], 
             [['date_added'], 'safe'],
             [['email', 'subject'], 'string', 'max' => 255], [['email'], 'email'], 
             [['name', 'match', 'pattern' => '/^[a-zA-Z]+$/', 
              'message' => 'Your username can only contain alphabetic characters']]

]; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Tray this:

```
    public function rules() { 
        return [ [['name', 'email', 'subject', 'content'], 'required'], 
                 ['name','match', 'pattern' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z., ]+$/;',
                'message' => 'Name can only contain Alphabet and Spaces only'],
                 [['date_added'], 'safe'],
                 [['email', 'subject'], 'string', 'max' => 255], [['email'], 'email'], 
    ]; }
```